# Elementor dropdown menu dissapears on mouse hoover

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am helping a friend with a Wordpress/Woocommerce project he is doing.

We are facing an issue with a dropdown menu. The menu item is named 'collections'. There is a product image with a zoom on hover function right underneath the menu. When you try to hover down the dropdown menu it disappears.

We tried messing with the z-indexes and even a jQuery selector script, but nothing worked.

[Link here](https://carpets.sunnydesigns.nl/product/no-4005/)

Can anyone please help out :)

Answer (score 0):

Your target is the z-index of your `.zoomContainer`.

```
<div class="zoomContainer" style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 389.587px; top: 239.25px; height: 1110.93px; width: 739.987px; z-index: 999;">..</div>
```

It's set to 999. Play with it and set it to a lower value.